# Qt installation on Mountain Lion from installer

Tags: qt, osx-mountain-lion

I wanted to install Qt on Mountain Lion. For this, I went to http://qt-project.org/downloads and downloaded the newest Qt library installer (4.8.3). I then followed the instructions, and at the end of the installation process, I got a message saying "The installation failed". Did anyone encounter problems with this version of Qt under Mountain Lion?

Thanks a lot!

Thomas.

P.S.: This is the full log from the installer:

```
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: @(#)PROGRAM:Install  PROJECT:Install-735
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: @(#)PROGRAM:Installer  PROJECT:Installer-614
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Hardware: MacBookPro9,1 @ 2.60 GHz (x 8), 8192 MB RAM
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Running OS Build: Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Env: PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Env: TMPDIR=/var/folders/3x/1w64hbq54698swps28n102q00000gp/T/
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Env: SHELL=/bin/bash
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Env: HOME=/Users/twalter
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Env: USER=twalter
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Env: LOGNAME=twalter
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Env: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-yL5eiv/Listeners
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Env: Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-kEy9gO/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Env: Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-gkJ0hE/Render
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Env: DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-WODr77/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Env: COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Env: __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F6:0:0
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Qt  Installation Log
Nov  1 10:48:43 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Opened from: /Volumes/Qt 4.8.3/Qt.mpkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = x-disc://Qt%204.8.3/Qt.mpkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/Qt.mpkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = x-disc://Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_tools.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_tools.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = x-disc://Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_libraries.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_libraries.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = x-disc://Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_docs.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_docs.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = x-disc://Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_examples.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_examples.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = x-disc://Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_headers.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_headers.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = x-disc://Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_imports.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_imports.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = x-disc://Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_plugins.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_plugins.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = x-disc://Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_translations.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: fileURLForURL = file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_translations.pkg
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Product archive /Volumes/Qt 4.8.3/Qt.mpkg trustLevel=100
Nov  1 10:48:44 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Referenced component packages (8) trustLevel=100
Nov  1 10:49:58 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: InstallerStatusNotifications plugin loaded
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local runner[99252]: Administrator authorization granted.
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: ================================================================================
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: User picked Standard Install
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Choices selected for installation:
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:   Upgrade: "Qt"
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:       Qt.mpkg : Qt Packages : 0.8.0.4.8
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:   Upgrade: "Qt Tools"
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:       Qt_tools.pkg : com.trolltech.qt4.tools : 4.8.0.4.8
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:   Upgrade: "Qt Libraries"
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:       Qt_libraries.pkg : com.trolltech.qt4.libs : 4.8.0.4.8
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:   Install: "Qt Documentation"
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:       Qt_docs.pkg : com.trolltech.qt4.docs : 4.8.0.4.8
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:   Install: "Qt Examples"
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:       Qt_examples.pkg : com.trolltech.qt4.examples : 4.8.0.4.8
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:   Upgrade: "Qt Headers"
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:       Qt_headers.pkg : com.trolltech.qt4.headers : 4.8.0.4.8
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:   Upgrade: "Qt Imports"
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:       Qt_imports.pkg : com.trolltech.qt4.imports : 4.8.0.4.8
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:   Upgrade: "Qt Plugins"
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:       Qt_plugins.pkg : com.trolltech.qt4.plugins : 4.8.0.4.8
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:   Upgrade: "Qt Translations"
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]:       Qt_translations.pkg : com.trolltech.qt4.translations : 4.8.0.4.8
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: ================================================================================
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: It took 0.00 seconds to summarize the package selections.
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: -[IFPKGDerivedDocument sortedPackageLocations]: result = (
        "file://localhost"
    )
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: location = file://localhost
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/Qt.mpkg
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_tools.pkg
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_libraries.pkg
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_docs.pkg
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_examples.pkg
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_headers.pkg
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_imports.pkg
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_plugins.pkg
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_translations.pkg
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: -[IFDInstallController(Private) _buildInstallPlan]: file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/Qt.mpkg
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Set authorization level to root for session
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local runner[99252]: Administrator authorization granted.
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Will use PK session
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Starting installation:
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Configuring volume "Macintosh HD"
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Preparing disk for local booted install.
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Free space on "Macintosh HD": 700.85 GB (700845834240 bytes).
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Create temporary directory "/var/folders/3x/1w64hbq54698swps28n102q00000gp/T//Install.992003AWHIN"
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: IFPKInstallElement (10 packages)
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Using authorization level of root for IFPKInstallElement
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: ----- Begin install -----
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: request=PKInstallRequest <10 packages, destination=/>
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: packages=(
        "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/Qt.mpkg>",
        "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_tools.pkg>",
        "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_libraries.pkg>",
        "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_docs.pkg>",
        "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_examples.pkg>",
        "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_headers.pkg>",
        "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_imports.pkg>",
        "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_plugins.pkg>",
        "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_translations.pkg>",
        "PKJaguarPackage <file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/Qt.mpkg>"
    )
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Will do receipt-based obsoleting for package identifier com.trolltech.qt4.tools (prefix path=)
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Will do receipt-based obsoleting for package identifier com.trolltech.qt4.libs (prefix path=)
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Will do receipt-based obsoleting for package identifier com.trolltech.qt4.headers (prefix path=)
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Will do receipt-based obsoleting for package identifier com.trolltech.qt4.imports (prefix path=)
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Will do receipt-based obsoleting for package identifier com.trolltech.qt4.plugins (prefix path=)
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Will do receipt-based obsoleting for package identifier com.trolltech.qt4.translations (prefix path=)
Nov  1 10:50:09 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_tools.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/1.sandbox/Root, uid=0)
Nov  1 10:50:10 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_libraries.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/1.sandbox/Root, uid=0)
Nov  1 10:50:11 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_docs.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/1.sandbox/Root, uid=0)
Nov  1 10:50:16 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_examples.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/1.sandbox/Root, uid=0)
Nov  1 10:50:20 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_headers.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/1.sandbox/Root, uid=0)
Nov  1 10:50:21 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_imports.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/1.sandbox/Root, uid=0)
Nov  1 10:50:21 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_plugins.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/1.sandbox/Root, uid=0)
Nov  1 10:50:21 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Extracting file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_translations.pkg (destination=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/1.sandbox/Root, uid=0)
Nov  1 10:50:21 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: update_dyld_shared_cache -overlay /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/1.sandbox/Root
Nov  1 10:50:25 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: prevent user idle system sleep
Nov  1 10:50:25 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: suspending backupd
Nov  1 10:50:25 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Shoving /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/Cleanup At Startup/PKInstallSandboxManager/1.sandbox/Root (3 items) to /
Nov  1 10:50:26 Macintosh.local install_monitor[99260]: Temporarily excluding: /Applications, /Developer, /Library, /System, /bin, /private, /sbin, /usr
Nov  1 10:50:33 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Executing script "./postflight" in /Volumes/Qt 4.8.3/packages/Qt_docs.pkg/Contents/Resources
Nov  1 10:50:33 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Executing script "./postflight" in /Volumes/Qt 4.8.3/packages/Qt_examples.pkg/Contents/Resources
Nov  1 10:50:33 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: ./postflight: env: python: No such file or directory
Nov  1 10:50:33 Macintosh.local install_monitor[99260]: Re-included: /Applications, /Developer, /Library, /System, /bin, /private, /sbin, /usr
Nov  1 10:50:34 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: releasing backupd
Nov  1 10:50:34 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: allow user idle system sleep
Nov  1 10:50:34 Macintosh.local installd[38810]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “Qt_examples.pkg”." UserInfo=0x7feaaa815be0 {NSFilePath=./postflight, NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_examples.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.trolltech.qt4.examples, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “Qt_examples.pkg”.} {
        NSFilePath = "./postflight";
        NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cQt_examples.pkg\U201d.";
        NSURL = "file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_examples.pkg";
        PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.trolltech.qt4.examples";
    }
Nov  1 10:50:34 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “Qt_examples.pkg”." UserInfo=0x7f9cd43c6ca0 {NSFilePath=./postflight, NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/Qt%204.8.3/packages/Qt_examples.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.trolltech.qt4.examples, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “Qt_examples.pkg”.}
Nov  1 10:50:35 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
Nov  1 10:50:35 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: IFDInstallController D4020140 state = 7
Nov  1 10:50:35 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
Nov  1 10:50:35 Macintosh.local Installer[99200]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.
```

Comment: One comment: I have XCode 4.5.1 installed, including the command line tools. I also installed gcc-42-5666.3-darwin11.pkg from http://r.research.att.com/tools (because I needed the fortran compiler which does not come with XCode command line tools anymore).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I earlier installed on Lion. May be you can try to compile Qt on Mac or try installing Qt 4.7.

This link may help: http://doc.qt.digia.com/latest/install-mac.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Compilation worked without problems. 

Now, I will test, whether I can install PyQt ...

Comment: Sorry ... new to Stack Overflow.